# NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)'

Tags: iphone, ios, json, nsdate

I'm getting this exception when I try to JSON encode NSDate object.I believe NSDate is not compatible for JSON encoding. but I must encode the date.Any solutions?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FIrst store your data in NSString. And then convert your string to NSDate.

You can refer SO:

[Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

[NSString to NSDate conversion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738363/nsstring-to-nsdate-conversion-problem)

[How to convert NSString to NSDate using NSDateFormatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396609/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-nsdate-using-nsdateformatter)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The OP is asking how to **encode** an NSDate. That means they should convert the NSDate to an NSString before inserting it into the dictionary they are attempting to JSON encode. My answer below shows an example solution.

Comment: not a good solution. its just a by-pass. I need to know how to make it work with NSDate itself or, if not, why this is happening.

Answer (score 7):

Convert NSDate to NSString and try to encode.

```
- (NSString *) changeDateToDateString :(NSDate *) date {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"hh mm" options:0 locale:locale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return dateString;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As noted, you must first convert your NSDate to an NSString. It's not immediately clear, however, which format the date should be represented in. The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format): "JSON itself does not specify how dates should be represented, but Javascript does" -- ISO8601.

Here is an ISO8601 conversion method from a helper category for NSDate, courtesy [Erica Sadun](https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions):

```
- (NSString *)ISO8601 {
    struct tm time;
    time_t interval = [self timeIntervalSince1970];
    gmtime_r(&interval, &time);
    char *x = calloc(1, 21);
    strftime_l(x, 20, "%FT%TZ", &time, gmtlocale);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:x];
    free(x);
    return string;
}
```

If you get an ISO8601 string back in a JSON payload and want to convert it to an NSDate, use this class method for NSDate:

```
+ (NSDate *)dateFromISO8601:(NSString *)string {
    if(!string) return nil;
    if (![string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) return nil;
    struct tm time;
    strptime_l([string UTF8String], "%FT%TZ", &time, gmtlocale);
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timegm(&time)];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried ?

```
updateDate = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

As Described Here : [SDK not supporting NSDate objects](https://github.com/stackmob/stackmob-ios-sdk/issues/1)

Follow these **Steps :**

**1. Convert the Date in JSON Format :**

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"Z"];
 NSString *updateDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%.0f000%@)/", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970],[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
```

**2. Embed In some array and POST the array.**

Comment: Why on earth would you be using float? float has 24 bit precisions. There's over a billion seconds since 1970. Which means your resolution is worse than a minute. Your date format is absolutely non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to store and retrieve a NSDate object in JSON would be to use the **timeIntervalSince1970** property of NSDate.

The returned NSTimeInterval (double) is pretty standard and can easily be converted back to a NSDate object using:

```
NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the date to a string before you try to encode it. There are enough examples everywhere so it should be easy to find

Answer (score 0):

For our case, we are using **Mantle** to convert an object to JSON and one of our objects with property NSDate is missing its JSONTransformer

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *expiryDate;
```

where:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)expiryDateJSONTransformer {
     return [MTLValueTransformer transformerUsingForwardBlock:^id(NSString *dateString, BOOL *success, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        return [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    } reverseBlock:^id(NSDate *date, BOOL *success, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
        return [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    }];
}

+ (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter {
    NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
    return df;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something like this in my body params encoder

```
// handle dates
              var _params = [String: Any]()
              params.forEach { (key, value) in
                if let date = value as? Date {
                    _params[key] = DateFormatter.iso8601Full.string(from: date)
                } else {
                    _params[key] = value
                }
              }

              return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: _params)
```